# Aspose Insert table

Tags: ms-word, insert, aspose

I have a C# .Net web app using MVC3.  I am using Aspose to create a document.  I need to insert a calculated table into a pre-defined position in the output document.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Woulkd I use a bookmark in the destination doc?  Use a textual tag.  I've been doing this for text....

```
"Here's is my document's WIN Theme  <<WinTheme>>.  My code inserts the text into the tag"
```

I use the below code to insert the win theme.  I would like to do something like for a table.

```
doc.Range.Replace(new Regex("[<][<]WinTheme[>][>]"), "text Being Inserted);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I retrieved the nodes in the document and looped through them. When I find the matching tag, I replace it with an emtpy string and then created a table and inserted using

```
dstDoc.LastSection.Body.AppendChild(aTable);
```

Then continued looping appending the other nodes

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems related to the mail merge feature of the Microsoft Word. Please go through the [Aspose.Words mail merge section](http://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Mail+Merge+and+Reporting) to get help regarding your requirement. If it still doesn't help then please do let me know. Please note that I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @SHahzad...I actually, I retrieved the nodes in the document and looped through them.  When I find the right tag, I replace it with an smmtpy string and then create a table and do dstDoc.LastSection.Body.AppendChild(CreateRiskTable(dstDoc, aTable));  You have some good comments.